# Apache rewrite rule adds 2 superflous slashes

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect all www to non-www with a google friendly 301 in apache2.2

It works basically but when I enter www.test.net in the browser I get redirected to test.net// and I would prefer without the double slash.

This is in my VHOST:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.test.net [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://test.net/$1 [L,R=301]
```

EDIT: It is even worse:

www.test.net/home in the browser gets redirected to test.net//home

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://test.net$1 [L,R=301]
```

or,

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://test.net/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The `/` is present in the string that's being matched, so you're adding the extra in your `$1`.